# injecting mocks with mockito and powermocks

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I was wondering how should I go about injecting a mocks - we have bunch of classes that do server calls, however our CI system can not access external resources and thus will not make a call to a server. Thus, the call has to be simulated and hardcoded values (such as response codes) needed to be return.

So, here is a snippet of a code:

```
  HttpPost httpRequest = new HttPost(uri);
  //some code here
   try{ 
      httpRequest.setEntity(entity);
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
      ...
  //other, irrelevant, code is here
```

So, is it possible to inject a mock into httpClient.execute(httpRequest) and return hardcoded response entity from a test unit?

Thank you

Comment: This might help. http://johannesbrodwall.com/2009/10/24/testing-servlets-with-mockito/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually mocking some object looks like this:

```
public class TestClass {

    private HttpServer server;

    public HttpServer getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(HttpServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void method(){
        //some action with server
    }
}
```

And test class:

```
public class TestClassTest {
    //class under test
    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        HttpServer mockServer = Mockito.mock(HttpServer.class);
        test.setServer(mockServer);
        //set up mock, test and verify
    }
}
```

Here you some useful links:

- [Code example](http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Testing_with_Mockito_-_JUnit_and_Mockito_Example)
- [Official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/w/list)